# 401 unauthorized error on admin api call - shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, fetch-api, shopify-api

I am facing unauthorized 401 error on shopify. I am using access token in fetch. I have used multiple ways like axios/xhr but still the issue is there. I have already tested this api call on postman and it is working fine on postman but not on shopify. How do i fix this issue. Am i missing any parameter in api call ? Please guide

```js
fetch('https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/graphql.json', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
              'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"query": stagedUploadsQuery,"variables": stagedUploadsVariables})
          })
            .then(response => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                console.log('Full response:', response);
              }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
              // Handle the data here
              console.log('Staged Upload Query Result:', data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Handle errors here
              console.error('Error during the fetch:', error);
            });
```

[image]

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` means the request is not allowed to contain any non CORS-safelisted request headers. The API could allow further headers via `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, but I am not sure if that applies with `mode: 'no-cors'`?

Comment: @CBroe so what do you suggest here ?

Comment: Should be `mode: 'cors'`, because this would clearly be a cross-origin request (and you _want_ access to the result.) And if that does not work, because the URL does not respond with the necessary headers - then that would most likely mean, that you are not supposed to consume this API from the client side in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe when i am using mode: 'cors' , it shows cors policy error. This api call works fine on postman and even when i am using this code on my shopify development store. It is working fine. The issue is, when i do the same api call on my client's store which btw is connected to Godady domain then it shows above error of authentication.

Comment: _"This api call works fine on postman"_ - postman is not a browser, and as such is not subject to CORS restrictions. _"and even when i am using this code on my shopify development store"_ - and by that you also mean a client-side request, yes? If so, then it is probably an issue of access token/client id not matching the domain this runs on, or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe postman confirmed me that i am using the right api call end point and it also confirmed me that i am using the right access token. So the issue lies in my fetch request on shopify.

Comment: What postman does _not_ confirm, is whether you are supposed to consume that API from the client side in the first place. (And upon my _explicit_ question, whether your "my shopify development store" comment meant that you _are_ doing that there, consuming it from the client side, got no response.) Seeing how this appears to be about admin functionality, I would assume this is probably _not_ meant for client-side use. All of the libraries mentioned under https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql#client_libraries appear to be for server-side languages/frameworks as well.

Comment: @CBroe forget about Postman. This code works fine on on my development store which we create through partner dashbord. That development store is not connected to any Godady domain. It is only based on shopify default url which is https://mystore.myshopify.com . When i use the code on a shopify store which is connected to godady domain then it shows the unauthorized error.

Comment: Then you probably need to add that domain somewhere in your shopify app settings.

Comment: @CBroe The app which i created through apps settins to generate Access Token , does not have option to add domain somewhere.

Comment: So your case is the third one listed here, https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/auth#types-of-authentication-and-authorization-methods - "Apps that are created in the Shopify admin", yes? Not sure if you access the admin interface _via_ the custom domain in that process, but if that was the case, and you created the access token before you added the godaddy domain to your setup, you might perhaps need to "rotate" your credentials? https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/auth/admin-app-access-tokens#rotating-api-credentials-for-admin-created-apps